# probleme with running Hello-World embeded neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

Need help with running Hello-World in embeded neo4j causes this error message appears

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotInTransactionException
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:228)    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.getResource(PersistenceManager.java:228)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.persistence.PersistenceManager.nodeCreate(PersistenceManager.java:155)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeManager.createNode(NodeManager.java:254)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.createNode(EmbeddedGraphDbImpl.java:305)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.createNode(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:105)
    at twiapp.embeded.main(embeded.java:37)
```

code is as below

```
public static void main(String args[]) { 
  graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(path);
   registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
   Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx(); 
  try {
      firstNode = graphDb.createNode(); 
      firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, "); 
      secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
      secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");
      relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS);
     relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");
      tx.success();
     } finally {
          tx.finish();
        }
     }
```

**Java Result: 1**

Comment: public static void main(String args[]) {
        graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(path);
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
        Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
        try { firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, ");
        secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
        secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");
        relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS);
        relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");

            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }

Comment: edit your question. instead of adding the code here

Comment: I dont have any know how here but could it be that you need to have a Transaction per Node you are opening?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like in the manual. [Wrap operations in a transaction](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.7/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html#_wrap_operations_in_a_transaction)

```
try ( Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx() )
{
  firstNode = graphDb.createNode(); 
  firstNode.setProperty("message", "Hello, "); 
  secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
  secondNode.setProperty("message", "World!");
  relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo(secondNode, RelTypes.KNOWS);
  relationship.setProperty("message", "brave Neo4j ");
  tx.success();
}
```